# types and functions C++

Tags: c++

```
class const_buffer
{
public:
  /// Construct an empty buffer.
  const_buffer()
    : data_(0),
      size_(0)
  {
  }

  /// Construct a buffer to represent a given memory range.
  const_buffer(const void* data, std::size_t size)
    : data_(data),
      size_(size)
  {
  }

  const void* data_;
  std::size_t size_;
}
```

data_ is defined as void*   and size_ is of type std::size_t.   They are not functions, but why you can do data_(data), size_(size)?     Looks like they take on parameters and acting like functions.

Answer (score 2):

The closest analogy to functions would be, that you're calling constructors of these types to initialize them. It's just a syntax, they don't "act" like functions.

Comment: so, any type can have a constructor, like int?

Comment: Depends on what do you understand by the term `constructor`. Please refer to the link provided at the top of your question.